# Auto Reset during programming Arduino

Tags: arduino-pro-mini, reset

I know this that when you try to program a pro mini without a DTR pin it will give you a error as the atmega needs to be reset during programming. So I had a doubt why does the microcontroller needs to be reset and clearly at which time you know at which moment does it reset ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Reset is necessary to activate the Bootloader and allow programming. Without the DTR signal the Reset button has to be pressed just before starting the upload from the Arduino IDE.

Comment: Is there any serial traffic before upload or is there anything like that the compiler sends any notification to the device.

Comment: The compiler does not know about the upload. It is avrdude that does the upload. The reset is generated by pulling the DTR signal. Please see http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/AutoResetRetrofit for more information about the auto-reset feature.

Comment: If the software is somehow unable to send the reset signal then how could I create reset signal without manually pressing the reset button.

Comment: What FTDI (USB-Serial bridge) are you using? Does it lack a DTR pin?

Comment: Actually I don't really have a DTR pin I have only TX RX and GND pin.

Comment: Is there any timeout for the bootloader to take a decision whether to go for programming or to load sketch ??? If yes then how much ?????

Comment: Yes, there is a timeout in the bootloader. After reset the bootloader will wait for a short period (second, see bootloader code) for a command. If no command is received and timeout the current sketch is called. Here is a bootloader hack tutorial https://learn.adafruit.com/arduino-tips-tricks-and-techniques/bootloader.